# Parse CSS and Javascript to see if it's compatible with browsers

Tags: javascript, web-development, css

Tools like [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/) is great for checking whether a feature is compatible with which browser. But is there a tool which **parses** an entire CSS and/or Javascript document and highlight which part is compatible with a browser you choose.

Ideally, I would simply paste my code in, select a browser (IE8) and see which parts are not supported.

Comment: Cross browser testing is always a complicated topic.
While for the JS you can use any Selenium solution (maybe using something like NightWatchJS (http://nightwatchjs.org) or any WebDriver (https://github.com/admc/wd , https://github.com/learnboost/soda, etc...) stuff) for the CSS it's a bit more trickier. Anyway, I found Needle which is CSS testing for Selenium: http://needle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are looking for but **before** checking for compatibility with one or more browsers I would check that you meet the **standards**.

There are a list of indispensable checking tools on the [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/) that you might check out.

This list includes a [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options) that will check your CSS against the standards rather than specific MS "Features" I would say that it is always a good idea to **start** by making your code standards compliant. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) will do the same for your JS.  Both will tell you where the problem(s) are as well as what.

Once you are meeting the standards there is a much higher chance that any given browser will work.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer but I'm afraid it is not what I am looking for. "Once you are meeting the standards there is a much higher chance that any given browser will work." - this is simply not true unfortunately. For example, `background-size: cover;` is a totally valid (as tested by the CSS Validator you suggested), but it will not work in Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Which is why I said "More Likely" rather than will - unfortunately there are still a lot of non-compliant browsers about, _(most easily spotted by the initials MS at the front)_.